# How do I extract a dictionary from a CDATA embedded in HTML?

Tags: python, html, cdata

I used python to scrape an HTML file, but the data I really need is embedded in a CDATA file.

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.website.com'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='react-container')
print(results.prettify())
```

The output is:

```
<div class="react-container" id="react-container">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.REACT_OPTS = {"components":[{"component_name":"","props":{},"router":true,"redux":true,"selector":"#react-container","ignoreMissingSelector":false}]}
```

I eventually want to iterate through the full CDATA dictionary to compare if certain dictionary values are present in another list.

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how I can extract and manipulate the contents of the CDATA file. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like JSON-data. There should be python utilities to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

This example will print string inside the `<script>` tag and then parses the data with `re`/`json` module:

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<div class="react-container" id="react-container">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.REACT_OPTS = {"components":[{"component_name":"","props":{},"router":true,"redux":true,"selector":"#react-container","ignoreMissingSelector":false}]}
// ]]>
</script>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

# select desired <script> tag
script_tag = soup.select_one('#react-container script')

# print contents of the <script> tag:
print(script_tag.string)

# parse the json data inside <script> tag to variable 'data'
data = json.loads( re.search(r'window\.REACT_OPTS = ({.*})', script_tag.string).group(1) )

# print data to screen:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
//<![CDATA[
window.REACT_OPTS = {"components":[{"component_name":"","props":{},"router":true,"redux":true,"selector":"#react-container","ignoreMissingSelector":false}]}
// ]]>

{
    "components": [
        {
            "component_name": "",
            "props": {},
            "router": true,
            "redux": true,
            "selector": "#react-container",
            "ignoreMissingSelector": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! What did you mean by 'react-container script'?

Comment: it's selector for your parent div (react-container)