# Parsing html by key values in python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I have the following html structure:

```
...
 
</script>
    <script charset="UTF-8" src="https://cdn-static-1.medium.com/_/fp/gen-js/main-base.bundle.v9GqvbREprarEikDLHPtIA.js" async></script>
    <script>
        // <![CDATA[
        window["obvInit"]({
                "references": {
                    "Collection": {
                        "1": {
                            "id": "1",
                            "name": "1",
...
                            "value": [{
                            "postId": "1",
                            "slug": "1",
...
```

And I want to get `"value"` array in some format that I could transfer to json later on.

The full path to the location is
`html > body. browser-chrome os-windows is-withMagicUnderlines v-unbound v-glyph v-glyph--m2-unbound is-noJs > script`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089496/how-do-i-extract-a-dictionary-from-a-cdata-embedded-in-html).

Comment: what you have shown there is Javascript - not a trace of HTML as far as I can see